# What is the meaning of the idiom "yo voy a ti"?

Tags: expresiones, puerto-rico

I have seen the phrase *ir a uno* used in a number of contexts.  I found on Twitter this image below. I am not sure what the expression means.

> Puerto Rico, ¡yo voy a ti!

Literally **I go to you** what does that mean? It's so simple, and I have been studying Spanish a number of years, yet I can't translate it.

[image]

Comment: Puerto Rico, I will be there. I think this is what the phrase means.

Comment: Probably may mean something different in different contexts. Please, provide some examples of usage. Seeing you example I would **guess** that she is twitting "I'm going to P.R. (for an event related to sports), but in other context could mean "I support you" or "I'm with you". My **guess** is that is an equivalent to "Estoy contigo", but I'm not familiar with the expression. This idiom is definitely not used in Spain.

Comment: @Diego it is very interesting this expression does not exist in Castillian

Comment: I am surprised nobody has pointed out that she is Monica Puig who was the first Puerto Rican athlete to win an Olympic gold medal. She too the tennis gold in Rio in 2016.

Comment: @mdewey I know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ESPAÑOL (English follows)**

"Ir" es un verbo que significa "moverse de un lugar hacia otro", e implica que el movimiento se produce hacia un lugar apartado del que se mueve (el actor) y del que indica la acción (el hablante).

"Venir" es un verbo con un significado parecido a "ir", pero que implica que el movimiento se produce hacia el lugar donde se encuentra el que indica la acción (el hablante).

Cuando el destino que se indica para esta acción es una persona (o varias), significa que el propósito de la acción es conseguir **estar juntos** (el/los actor/es, con el/los destinatario/s); este "estar juntos" puede significar simplemente permanecer en un lugar (estado físico), aunque lo más habitual es que se refiera a compartir unas intenciones o un sentimiento (estado psíquico).

Así podemos encontrar en varias obras literarias y canciones las expresiones `ven a mí` o `voy a ti`, expresando (en un sentido poético o figurado) la intención de **permanecer juntos** en un lugar físico o emocional con la intención de apoyar uno al otro o apoyarse mutuamente.

Por tanto, en la frase

> Puerto Rico, yo voy a ti!

el significado es como en **yo voy a estar contigo** (para apoyarte).

---

**ENGLISH**

"*Ir*" (To go) is a verb meaning "to move from one place to another," and implies that the movement occurs to a secluded place from who moves (the actor) and from who indicates the action (the speaker).

"*Venir*" (To come) is a verb with a resemblance to "*ir*" meaning, but it implies that the movement occurs to the place where the speaker is (who is indicating the action).

When the destination indicated for this action is a person (or several), it means that the purpose of the action is ***estar juntos*** (to be together, the performer/s with the recipient/s); this "being together" can mean simply stay in one place (physical state), although it is common to refer to share some intentions or feeling (psychological state).

Thus we can find in several literary works and songs the expressions *`ven a mí`* or *`voy a ti`*, expressing (in a poetic way or figuratively) intend to **stay together** on a physical or emotional place with intent to one support the other, or both to support each other.

Therefore, in the phrase

> *Puerto Rico, yo voy a ti!*

the meaning is like in ***yo voy a estar contigo*** (to support you).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is some ambiguity in the phrase. As @Diego says. The way it is may mean several things but the nearest ones are:

> I bet to you
>
> I support you
>
> I'm with you

`I'm going to you` is some approach and can be taken in consideration but it will be a bad use of the Spanish language.

Answer (score 2):

It means "I believe in you" in Puerto Rican. You have to remember Puerto Rican is the slang language of Spanish.

Comment: I think you mean a dialect of Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

**Puerto Rican Slang** "Voy a ti y pago doble" o "Voy a usted y pago doble" is similar to "Go ahead.  You got this".  It's an affirmation of your ability to overcome a challenge or do something difficult.

Comment: So far the best explanation and translation: Puerto Rico, you got this.

Answer (score 2):

It just means, "I'm cheering for you, you got this." At least in Puerto Rico ...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the literal wouldn't help much in this context.
However, if you were to compare this to "I'm down with you" similar to "I would bet on you"
the assurance that you are worth having confidence and support on!

Answer (score 0):

The expression "Yo voy a ti" means rooting for someone.

You're saying "I know you can win" or "I believe in you". They are words of encouragement.

Answer (score 0):

Puerto Rico, ¡yo voy a ti!, aunque esta en singular, en ese contexto general de apoyo, puede interpretarse de varias maneras;

- Puerto Rico, ¡Yo estoy contigo! (Yo te apoyo)
- Puerto Rico, ¡Yo y todos estamos contigo! (te apoyamos).
- Puerto Rico, ¡Estamos contigo! (todos te mostramos nuestro apoyo).

Answer (score 0):

I always interpreted this to mean like, "you go!", like in the expression "you go, girl!."

It's another way of saying, to get on with your bad self.